# How to make a call to server when I scroll the tableview in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to send one request when I scroll the tableview up and another request when I scroll down.I dont have any idea how to achieve this.Can anyone suggest me how can I go with this??

Thank you,
Monish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protocol UITableViewDelegate conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate, so all you need to do is to implement the methods `-scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and -`scrollViewDidScroll` directly in your UITableViewDelegate implementation and they will be called automatically if the implementation class is set as delegate to your UITableView.

just implement :

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    NSLog(@"done");

}
```

Also refer :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate; // called on finger up if user dragged. decelerate is true if it will continue moving afterwards

- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView; // called when setContentOffset/scrollRectVisible:animated: finishes. not called if not animating
```

Comment: :Thank u very much for ur prompt reply.I used the delegate method scrollViewWillBeginDragging and when I scroll uo and down the same method is calling.How can I handle the scroll up and down of tableview?

Comment: look at my answer, there is described about contentOffset

Answer (score 0):

Use methods from UIScrollViewDelegate. UITableViewDelegate inherits them.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, and UITableViewDelegate conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate. So the delegate you attach to the table view will get events such as scrollViewDidScroll:, and you can keep track of the instance variable 'contentOffset' of your table view to find out where you tableView was moved up or down.

Also I'd advise you to use something like:

```
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(yourRequestMethodInProperThreadBody) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

In order not to affect the movements of your table view when request is being performed.